# Reading from file(File System) without node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm trying to upload files to Google Drive using this function, taken from their Node.js **example:**

```
function uploadFiles() {
  var fileMetadata = {
    'name': 'test-1.jpg'
  };
  var media = {
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    body: fs.createReadStream('img/test-1.jpg')
  };
  gapi.client.drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
  }, function(err, file) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
    }
  });
}
```

My problem here is the `fs.createReadStream()` line.

Since Node.js is a server-side tool and `require()` does not exist in the browser, how can I create a byte stream from a file in JavaScript without using Node.js?

**EDIT:** - `gapi.client.drive.files.create()` problem

```
 function readFile(evt) {
            var fData = [];
            var f = evt.target.files[0];
            if (f) {
                var r = new FileReader();
                r.readAsText(f);
                fData.unshift(f.name,f.type);
               var myInt = setInterval(function() {
                    if (r.readyState == 2) {
                        fData.push(r.result);
                         uploadFiles(fData);
                        clearInterval(myInt);
                    }
                }, 50);
            } else {
                alert("Failed to load file");
            }

        }

        function uploadFiles(dataArray) {
            var fileMetadata = {
                'name': dataArray[0]
            };
            var media = {
                mimeType: dataArray[1],
                body: dataArray[2]
            };
            gapi.client.drive.files.create({
                resource: fileMetadata,
                media: media,
                fields: 'id'
            }, function(err, file) {
                console.log("Reached!");
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
                }
            });
        }

        document.getElementById('upFile').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use filereader on client side to read file data. use this demo code and try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function readSingleFile(evt) {
                var f = evt.target.files[0];
                if (f) {
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    r.onload = function(e) { 
                        var contents = e.target.result;
                    }
                    r.readAsText(f);
                } else {
                    alert("Failed to load file");
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
        </script>
```

Comment: Your solution works, however, the gapi.client.drive.files.create method is not returning an error or file id. I have tried debugging my code but I fail to see what the problem is. I have edited my original post with my current iteration of the upload files function.